# How to configure a image in navigator in lotus notes?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to configure a image which needs to change dynamically. I tried by adding the image from image resources and by using the embedded element i added that image in a form. But i want to add in navigator. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain that Navigators pre-date the addition of image resources to Domino Designer (no, make that 100% certain!), and that functionality to add image resources to them was never added. Navigators may not have been formally deprecated, but they have effectively been superceded by Outlines and Pages for more than a decade.